# writing parsed html to file in R using xpath

Tags: html, r, xpath, web-scraping

I'm having a problem writing my parsed html to a file. I have this data from a table specified from xpath but when I try to write it to a file, I get "Error in cat(list(...)).

```
> fileUrl <- "http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp"
> library(XML)
> htmlFile <- htmlTreeParse(fileUrl, useInternal = TRUE)
> # and then I grab the table
> urlParse <- xpathSApply(htmlFile, "//table[@class='reference']")
> urlParse[[1]]
[[1]]
<table class="reference" style="width:100%">
  <tr><th>Number</th>&#13;
    <th>First Name</th>&#13;
    <th>Last Name</th>      &#13;
    <th>Points</th>&#13;
</tr>
  <tr><td>1</td>&#13;
    <td>Eve</td>&#13;
    <td>Jackson</td>        &#13;
    <td>94</td>&#13;
</tr>
  <tr><td>2</td>&#13;
    <td>John</td>&#13;
    <td>Doe</td>        &#13;
    <td>80</td>&#13;
</tr>
  <tr><td>3</td>&#13;
    <td>Adam</td>&#13;
    <td>Johnson</td>        &#13;
    <td>67</td>&#13;
</tr>
  <tr><td>4</td>&#13;
    <td>Jill</td>&#13;
    <td>Smith</td>      &#13;
    <td>50</td>&#13;
</tr>
</table>
```

this is fine, but when I write this to a file, I get:

```
> write(urlParse[[1]], file = "file.txt") 
Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'externalptr') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

but when I do something like:

```
> write(c(3234,234,23,4,234), file = "file.txt")
```

everything is fine. Is it because it's a list? I tried urlParse[1], toString(urlParse[1]), urlParse[[1]][1]. Not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is currently represented by C-level objects. You need to convert it to a string.
`saveXML` can be used to do this:

```
fileUrl <- "http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp"
library(XML)
htmlFile <- htmlTreeParse(fileUrl, useInternal = TRUE)
urlParse <- xpathSApply(htmlFile, "//table[@class='reference']")
myXML <- saveXML(urlParse[[1]])
write(myXML, file = "file.txt")
```

or simply

```
saveXML(urlParse[[1]], file = "file.txt")
```